# Unable to fetch a patch on github (openembedded repository: unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch)

Tags: github, fetch

**Setup**

On Yocto environment, I have a bitbake recipe which fetch a patch on github:

```
SRC_URI = " \
        [...]
        https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/meta-oe/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch;name=patch \
"
```

When fetching this patch I have the error: ERROR 404: Not Found (since a few days).

**Issue**

WARNING: Failed to fetch URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/meta-oe/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch;name=patch, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 8, output:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/meta-oe/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch:
2020-08-19 12:21:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.

ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/meta-oe/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch;name=patch'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

**Tests**

I tried to access the link directly on internet, it doesn't work.

Also tried with the following link, doesn't work (without raw.githubusercontent.com option):
https://github.com/openembedded/meta-oe/blob/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch

I tried to find this patch on github with no success:

- Find in *openembedded/meta-openembeded* not *openembedded/meta-oe* (https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch) **not the same patch**
- Find in http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel-edison/tree/meta-intel-edison-distro/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump-4.6.1/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch?h=master **not the same project**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please find the new link below:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpdump/unnecessary-to-check-libpcap.patch

Seems like the url changed.